# Detect optional property at runtime

Tags: typescript, properties

```
class Person{
   name: string;
   age?: number;
}


function simpleGenericValidation(someone: Person){
     for (let prop of someone){
          if (prop === 'undefined')
           //is prop optional in Person?
     }
}
```

Is there a way to know at runtime if a property (someone.age) was declared optional? (excluding a possible solution using annotations)

Comment: The type system *only* exists at compile time. At run time, you have plain JavaScript executing and all of the types are both erased and don't even exist. There is no real way to extract any of the TS type information. What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you need that information? There is likely a different solution to [your core problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @VLAZ I was trying to implement a simple validation: When some object is passed to a function, a primary validation was that non-optional props were filled. The situation would be when receiving serialized objects where you get flat objects.

Comment: @tru7, no, there is no way to do it without extra information like passing an array of required field names to `simpleGenericValidation`
Still it's a bit of a weird thing you are trying to do, usually you first do validation and then let typescript know that `person` variable is of type `Person`, you are doing the opposite which is not the way it is supposed to work

Comment: Then I suggest making the validation using runtime logic. This can be made configurable per property with more code if you expand it to a library but it's likely that there are validation libraries that handle this. As I said, there is no way to interrogate the type system at runtime to do that. Do note that your current code has at least three problems I can see. 1. `for...of` will iterate over the *values* of properties, not their keys. You don't know what the current property is. 2. `age` is optional which means that it might not exist, not that it might be `undefined`. Assuming you have

Comment: [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled, the `null` and `undefined` values are removed from the pool of any other type so *if* `age` is present, it can only be a number. 3. `prop === "undefined"` checks if the value is the *string* `"undefined"`, to check if it's the *value*, then you need either `prop === undefined` or `typeof prop === "undefined"`

Comment: yes, the question just to make sure there was no simpler way than doing annotations on each optional property, something like @optional (but it seemed redundant to me so close to the ":?"  :-)